# Custom order list of links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of links that are by default sorted alphabetically. For example

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Aeroplanes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Diggers</a></li>
</ul>
```

This list is auto generated and in real life about has about 30 links, how can I easily order these with little overhead using javascript/jquery. The order will be changing often to boost categories depending on season/popularity a number of other deciding factors.

Comment: We're here to help debug any problem code _you've already tried and posted here_. We generally won't do the work for you.

Comment: Select the elements, apply a custom function to `sort()` with your logic, then re-append the elements to the containing `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**TinySort**](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) is a small script that sorts HTMLElements. It sorts by text- or attribute value, or by that of one of it's children. The examples below should help getting you on your way.

This **doesn't** use jQuery and it is fast in performance.

> TinySort used to be a jQuery plugin but was rewritten to remove the jQuery dependency. It is now smaller and faster (and has no dependencies). Functionality is the same but changes have been made to the parameters and options.

Just use this way:

```
tinysort (NodeList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.1.1/tinysort.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Aeroplanes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Diggers</a></li>
  
</ul>
<script>
  tinysort('ul>li');
</script>
```